# ping: subdomain.example.com: Temporary failure in name resolution - Ubuntu Lightsail Instance and Route53 with Public Hosted Zone

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, ubuntu-20.04, amazon-lightsail, reverse-dns

I have been searching solution since last 2 days and tried my best to solve myself, but I think I need help now.

Here is my setup

- AWS Lightsail Ubuntu 20.04 instance with Public/Static IP[image]

---

- Route53 Public Hosted Zone with following setup [image]

---

- I also tried to test record using Route53 Test Record option and everything seems to work fine.[image]

**Problem**
When I ping my lightsail instance public/static ip, it works fine.
When I try to ping **subdomain.example.com** or **example.com**, I get "Temporary failure in name resolution". I have configured nginx server and I am expecting a page in response to request to my subdomain.

- Do I need to setup something in my Lightsail server instance??
- OR am I missing something in Route53 configuration ??

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending hours of searching and understanding the main cause, I found out the solution.

So the main problem was mismatch **NameServer** values in Registered Domain, and the **NameServer** provided by the Hosted Zone.

I purchased the domain from Amazon using Route53. This means my DNS provider is Amazon and it also creates a Hosted Zone for you first time, using which you can create records and define routing. I had deleted the Hosted Zone after domain purchase.

If you delete your hosted zone and recreate later, then you get different DNS setting which mismatches with your First-time created DNS settings.

Later, I created the Hosted Zone again.

Now, here is my current situation.

- Route53 -> Domains -> Registered Domains
  [image]
- Hosted Zone DNS settings
  [image]

Look at the RED rectangular sections and you will find out that DNS values are different. **This was the main problem**

This happens when we delete / create / delete again / re-create the hosted zones but the DNS values remains same in the Domain -> Registered Domains.

**Solution**: Copy DNS values of Hosted Zone, and update to the Registered Domain section.

Read the reply here, its helpful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236377

Hope this would help others as well. :)

Comment: it helps me, but my problem is a bit different, I have a sub-domain with a port. Any idea, how to configure this? similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74286308/7991798