# How to setup port to subdomain in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache, proxy, amazon-route53

I have a domain (e.g. example.com) registered with godaddy.com and use AWS for hosting.
Nameserver on Godaddy later added to AWS

[image: godaddy nameserver]

I have an ubuntu (t2.medium) apache server installed. My project in Docker has LAMP, ELK, Node, React, and Postgres installed. Everything works on the local system using direct ports. Few ports open in my project i.e.

- example.com:3000 react app [frontend]
- example.com:5601 kibana app
- example.com:5050 postgradmin app
- example.com/radius php applicatinn [backend]
- example.com:8080 phpmyadmin app

my desired URLs are:

- example.com:3000 react app [frontend] => http://example.com
- example.com:5601 kibana app => http://kibana.example.com
- example.com:5050 postgradmin app => http://postgradmin.example.com
- example.com/radius php applicatinn [backend] => http://example.com/radius
- example.com:8080 phpmyadmin app => http://phpmyadmin.example.com

I have tried a few things but nothing is working. on route53

[image: route53]

tried reverse proxy on apache by adding separate conf files e.g.

**default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**kibana.conf**

```
Listen 5601

<VirtualHost *:5601>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    ServerName kibana.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**pgadmin.conf**

```
Listen 5050

<VirtualHost *:5050>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    ServerName pgadmin.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

when I run `docker-compose up` on EC2, http://example.com/radius works fine. but others do not (e.g. http://kibana.example.com). but if try with port directly (e.g. example.com:5601) it's working. but I want to use a sub-domain not a domain with a port.

How to do that?

reverse proxy I tried as mentioned in the description but it's not working properly

Comment: checkout this, https://askubuntu.com/a/1444291/885020

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want your domains to be publicly accessible. You need to create records for all domains.

Second, if you want to access by only domains without port, you should create multiple blocks of virtual host listening to only port 80, and then do the routing base on domains your server received

Example can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html)